# How to create `input_fn` to use as argument in `.fit()`?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to train a cnn model with some images I've labeled. I'm new to TensorFlow. and here is what I've done :

```
def read_labeled_image_list(image_list_file):
    f = open(image_list_file, 'r')
    filenames = []
    labels = []
    for line in f:
        filename, label = line[:-1].split(' ')
        filenames.append(filename)
        index0 = 1 if int(label) == 0 else 0
        index1 = 1 if int(label) == 1 else 0
        labels.append([index0, index1])
    return filenames, labels

def read_images_from_disk(input_queue):
    label = input_queue[1]
    file_contents = tf.read_file(input_queue[0])
    example = tf.image.decode_jpeg(file_contents, channels=1)
    return example, label
```

the use of "read_images_from_disk" as my input_fn:

```
image_list, label_list = 
          read_labeled_image_list("./images_training/training_list.txt")

images = tf.constant(image_list, dtype=tf.string)
labels = tf.constant(label_list, dtype=tf.int32)

# Makes an input queue
input_queue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([images, labels],
                                            num_epochs=30,
                                                shuffle=True)

image, label = read_images_from_disk(input_queue)

# Train the model
graph_classifier.fit(
    input_fn=read_images_from_disk(input_queue),
    steps=20000,
    monitors=[logging_hook])
```

I get the following error:

```
features, labels = input_fn()
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the error is that the `input_fn` argument in the `fit` method is supposed to be a callable. You could then try:

```
def read_images_from_disk(input_queue):
    label = input_queue[1]
    file_contents = tf.read_file(input_queue[0])
    example = tf.image.decode_jpeg(file_contents, channels=1)
    return example, label

def my_input_func():
 return read_images_from_disk(input_queue)

# Train the model
graph_classifier.fit(
    input_fn=my_input_func,
    steps=20000,
    monitors=[logging_hook])
```

I would also recommend to read carefully 
[the official doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/input_fn) on `input_func`.